# UI & Usability questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, usability

Do you think there is (or should be) a place for questions concerning UI design and usability on Stack Overflow? I don't mean the "how do I achieve X with technology Y" kind of questions, but those that deal with issues of design (colour, layout, affordance, etc.)

I realise that such questions deal less with programming directly, but they are the kinds of things that may programmers deal with on a daily basis. There have been a few times when I've considered asking such a question, but have withheld from doing so.

I doubt that a site dedicated to such issues will become a part of the SO family, so is there a place for them anywhere here?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33836/which-forum-if-any-is-best-for-questions-about-ui-design-and-usability

Answer (score 10):

It may be worthwhile to check out [User Experience.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/). It is the Stack Overflow of Usability and User Experience in general.

Answer (score 2):

While it's not a specific how do I implement X, the question is valid as it could (perhaps should) influence the language used, the whole approach taken (MVC, MVP, MVVM etc.).

So perhaps we should take each question on it's merits and not be aggressive when closing.

Comment: NOTE: This answer was written before the UX site existed.

Answer (score 2):

If you can ask general design (including design pattern) questions on SO, you should be able be fine asking usability questions. Usability is clearly an aspect of software engineering, and I think SO should focus on all aspects of software development, including usability. The only aspects of software engineering that are beyond stack overflow are the more management type questions, and even so, some process questions are still appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If your question was an attempt to avoid an [angry fruit salad](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/A/angry-fruit-salad.html) and contained screen shots, I'd  vote for it and (likely) answer it.

The problem with this type of question is that is heavily influenced by the personal taste of the person answering it. In most cases, it would likely turn into a discussion unless your question was narrowed enough (e.g Is button Y placed too close to button X?).