# Which forum, if any, is best for questions about UI design and usability?

Tags: support, scope

I see questions from time to time on SO about usability and UI design, and I haven't noticed them getting closed. At the same time, UI design and usability seem like they might be a better fit for SU. What do you all think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is now a beta site on stackexchange dedicated to user interfaces: https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not *a forum* right? ;-)

Comment: Since the OP was mentioning SO and SU (and is writing on meta), I assumed the word "forum" was improperly used as a general synonym of "online community" :)

Comment: I know :-) (And: it is a good answer!)

Answer (score 10):

I don't think Super User would be appropriate, as it is about the *use* of software and systems, not the creation of it.  Unless it is specifically relating to web design (in which case [doctype](http://doctype.com/) is exactly correct), your best bet is still probably Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

If it is about web design, try [doctype](http://doctype.com/).

Comment: There's a big difference between design & usability. No downvote because you specify design, but usability concerns are (IMHO) a totally SO-oriented topic.

Comment: @John Rudy: Did I say something different?

Comment: It depends on whether the design aspect is software related only or also encompasses aspects of the hardware platform involved. Software related questions would sit well on the software design site but those involving hardware questions might better be posed on the electronics/hardware design sites?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the design aspect is software related only or also encompasses aspects of the hardware platform involved. Software related questions would sit well on the software design site but those involving hardware questions might better be posed on the electronics/hardware design sites?